# Issue downloading some files using PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, download

I have a script that downloads PDF files after logging into another site. It has so far worked great for all sites but I am now getting something strange with a new site I'm scraping: some of the files downloaded are 1kb (i.e it didn't work) while others work just fine. Using the download link in the browser opens the "do you want to save this file" window and the file is correct there.

here is my code (I include both the general curl parameters used throughout the scrape, and the final part where I try downloading the files):

```
//Initial connection to login page
$header[] = 'Host: www.domain.com';
$header[] = 'Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$header[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
$header[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.domain.com/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.domain.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieLocation);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieLocation);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$webpage = curl_exec($ch);

//Then several operations to login, grab the list of links to PDF download files (...)

//Loop through the array containing the url of the file to download and save it to a folder (writable)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
foreach($foundBills as $key => $bill)
{
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $bill['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    $pdfFile = curl_exec($ch);
    $randomFileName = rand_string(20); //generates a 20 char long random string
    $newPDF = $userBillsRoot.$randomFileName.'.pdf';
    write_file($newPDF, $pdfFile, 'wb'); //using a Codeigniter function to save the file
}
```

The files are under 1mb each. Any ideas? How can I see more details about why it's not working (e.g timeout)? Thanks!

Comment: Calling `curl_error` will help you see what is going wrong: http://us2.php.net/curl_error.   Also, don't forget to close your curl session with `curl_close`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php

Comment: have you opened those 1kb files in a text editor to see what's in there? Plus, your `$pdfFile = curl_exec` stuff is assuming that nothing will ever fail. Never assume that when dealing with external resources, especially http fetches. ALWAYS check for failure.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy curl_error returns an empty string (and I use curl_close a bit later in the script)

Comment: @MarcB I've left out the failure handling bit. The file in notepad shows "Failed to download PDF"

Comment: Please try this method it works form me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285025/how-to-solve-curl-corrupting-file-during-download